# Use function to add choices to select form Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony2-easyadmin

I'm currently developping a Symfony application (v2.8) with two main bundles : EasyAdmin and FOSUserBundle.

I have users with a particular role and I'm using a 'findBy' with an array to retrieve those users.

I would like to override the form of my admin controller to fill a select form choices with those users. I know it's possible to do it with an array but I want something dynamic if I add or delete some users.

I don't know how can I call a function from one of my controllers (or do I have to declare it as a service ?) to add choices to select form from a query.

Here is an example of what I would like :

```
$formBuilder->add('field_to_override', 'choice', array(
   'choices' => **my_function**,
   'multiple' => true,
   'expanded' => true,
));
```

I hope I'm clear in my explanation.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Just to note that using a string literal like `'choice'` for a field type is deprecated in 2.8 - always use the classname of the field type, e.g. `ChoiceType::class`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using an [EntityType field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html), which is a specialized form of Choice field which uses Doctrine entities for the choices.

It is possible to specify a [custom query](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities) for the choices too, e.g.

```
$builder->add('users', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
));
```

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your help ! I've tried this solution but i'm getting an exception :

'The options "class", "query_builde" do not exist'. Then symfony gives me the possible options but none are close to 'class' and 'query_builder'.

Comment: Make sure you have pulled in those classes, i.e. with

`use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;`

Comment: It's not working.
I'm wondering if it's not because of Easy Admin bundle ?
Easy Admin is creating all the forms dynamically according to the entities you specify to it in config.yml
Maybe it's just not possible in this bundle...

Comment: My bad !
Forgot some changes (EntityType::class), it's working now !
Thank you very much !